# Group and Sort object with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to apply group and sort on objects.

```
var emplData = [{
    "company": "companyA",
    "title": "positionA",
    "office": "Boston",
    "first-name": "Mike",
    "last-name": "Bloom",
    "profile-url": "url"
}, {
    "company": "companyA",
    "title": "positionD",
    "office": "Amsterdam",
    "first-name": "Adam",
    "last-name": "Smart",
    "profile-url": "url"
}, {
    "company": "companyB",
    "title": "positionB",
    "office": "Toronto",
    "first-name": "Tina",
    "last-name": "Carmichael",
    "profile-url": "url"
}, {
    "company": "companyB",
    "title": "positionA",
    "office": "Chicago",
    "first-name": "Seth",
    "last-name": "Big",
    "profile-url": "url"
}, {
    "company": "companyC",
    "title": "positionC",
    "office": "St. Louis",
    "first-name": "Carla",
    "last-name": "Elsas",
    "profile-url": "url"
}]
```

I like to group the data by `company` and then sort by office (ascending order). I'm using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to group and it returns similar to object below.

```
var grpData = _.groupBy(emplData, 'company');

  {
    CompanyA:[{object1}, {object2} etc.],
    CompanyB: [{object1}, {object2} etc.],
    CompanyC: [{object1}, {object2} etc.]
  }
```

Now each object inside the grouped array has properties including office, I can't get the results I need to sort the data by it so we have an ascending order.

I have tried below method but doesn't seem to work.

```
var srtData = _.sortBy(grpData , function (i) {
    $(i).each(function (i2, val) {
        return val.office;
    });
});
```

Anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not sort and then group? Then the result will be a collection grouped by company name each holding sorted array of objects (asc. by office name)

```
var grpData = _.groupBy(_.sortBy(emplData, "office"), 'company');
```

Comment: This is a nice and quick way to do it! Thanks Sami

Comment: The docs don't guarantee `groupBy` is stable, right? This is a lucky implementation detail?

Comment: `lodash` in contrast does guarantee a stable ordering when using `groupBy`: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy